# How to get list of rows of selected sheet in Smartsheet using REST?

Tags: rest, smartsheet-api

I'm trying to get `list of rows` of selected sheet. I went for `REST API` for `rows` [List of row's related calls](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#rows) but didn't get any resource to get `list of rows`.

How can I get list of rows? or the REST call have not been written yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a list of rows by using the [Get Sheet](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-sheet) operation. The response will contain the list of rows in the sheet, the list of columns in the sheet (which you'll need to interpret the **cells** data within the rows collection), along with sheet-level properties and any other data you've requested by using the **include** parameter.